# Call to undefined method attributeValueExists()

Tags: magento-1.8, attributes, product-attribute

i created new attribute called 'brands' as dropdown menu have some values like "nike,puma,..." and added it to the default attribute set
i try to get the attribute id to add it to product when insert new one

```
$brand_id = $this->attributeValueExists('brands',$pro->brand->name );
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$product->setBrands($brand_id);
```

but i have error "`Fatal error: Call to undefined method attributeValueExists()` "
Thank in Advance..

Comment: Where did you use this code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Checking for attribute value existence. What does this do?](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/9671/checking-for-attribute-value-existence-what-does-this-do)

Answer (score 0):

This function does not exist in a fresh Magento installation

I think you maybe copied that from, for instance, [Checking for attribute value existence. What does this do?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/9671/checking-for-attribute-value-existence-what-does-this-do)

In that case, you should copy that function code in the model / helper / block you are calling your posted code